# Saving URLs in Woocommerce product attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get Woocommerce to save an URL as a product attribute. Problem is that URL contains some URL-encoded data like "%25" which Woocommerce doesn't save.
I tried a more simple example of creating a new attribute, called it "MyTestAttribute" and added a value of "Test value 123%456".
What Woocommerce saved was "Test value 1236", without %45.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You should better save the url as custom term meta data for each product attribute term… You can use for example Advanced Custom fields free plugin for that, [to add an additional custom URL field.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)